# How to add NLTK corpora to a google cloud function?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, nltk

I am trying to run Google cloud function which involves the use of NLTK. I had added 
textblob == 0.15.3
nltk == 3.4.3
to the requirement.txt. But every time I run the script it crashes and the log shows "Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:".

I know we need to download NLTK corpora to run the script in a local system. But not sure of how to download it in Google Cloud Functions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Akhil can you please share how actually you solved this issue? I'm facing the same issue. The correct answer doesn't seem to grasp the problem you're facing, as you can't interactively download anything on cloud functions.

Comment: Mkey, As I had to use just the text blob, I just had to download 2 corpora instead of the whole corpora. So I specifically mentioned nltk.download('brown') at the start of the script. It was slowed down my script a bit initially (like cold-start) but I was able to use that.
Another option is to deploy it in a basic compute engine instead of the cloud function.
Hope this helps

Comment: I actually solved it. the answer was that you needed to download it like `nltk.download("twitter_samples", download_dir = "/nltk_data")` in my case at least ;)

Comment: Good to know that. if possible please add that as an answer so that it helps other developers facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the nltk_data through my Travis Pipeline:

```
    # To install the core NLTK package
    pip install nltk   

    # Installs only the extra packages you need. You could also use 'all' instead. 
    python -m nltk.downloader punkt averaged_perceptron_tagger wordnet
```

Then you can copy the folder into your function folder, and zip it up:

```
    mkdir -p function/nltk_data/
    cp -a ~/nltk_data/. function/nltk_data/
    cp -a path/to/your/code/. function/
```

Be sure to set the NLTK_DATA environment variable. As my folder structure was

```
    - nltk_data/
    - main.py
    - requirements.txt
```

I just needed to set NLTK_DATA=nltk_data, and then python can find the files.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to specify dependencies for Cloud Functions written in Python: using the pip package manager's requirements.txt file or packaging local dependencies alongside your function. [There](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) you can find instructions. 
Also check [this](https://github.com/keon/CodeGAN/issues/1) link for possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this method and as it was taking a bit longer to run, I thought there might be an alternative way. Thank you very much.