# Include NLTK in Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, nltk

I am trying to deploy a google cloud function with lemmatization and tokenizer from NLTK library of python. NLTK required punct and wordnet packages to be downloaded using

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punct')
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

Hence these cannot be specified in the requirements.txt file. The only thing that can be mentioned in requirement.txt is nltk.

I did go over [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586527/how-to-add-nltk-corpora-to-a-google-cloud-function) that lead me to google documentation page about [specifying dependencies in python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) and followed all steps there.

First I moved entire virtual environment's dependencies into a directory called lib using

```
pip install -t lib nltk
```

And then I created `__init__.py` file inside the lib directory. And changed all my import statement to import from lib. However, when using the nltk package from lib directory, I constantly get error thrown which I believe is due to relative path.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
  File "/Users/aakashpatel/Documents/resume-compare/lib/nltk/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`

And if I look under `lib/nltk` folder's `__init__.py` file there is an import statement `from nltk.internals import config_java` which it cannot find because it has to be converted to `from lib.nltk.internals import config_java`. And I cannot just go ahead and change this one thing because there will be lot of other places where the import is simply mentioned as from nltk or something.

How can I solve this issue? Am I not following all steps for deploying to Google Cloud Function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You need to add path to lib directory in your `$PYTHONPATH` variable. You can simply write

```
import sys
sys.path.append('lib')
```

But this alone will not resolve the issue. NLTK downloads are saved in `nltk_data` directory so that directory has to be copied to `lib` folder or folder of your package and then append path to the `nlkt.data`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('lib/')

import lib.nltk as nltk
nltk.data.path.append('lib/nltk_data/')
```

So code block at the top should resolve NLTK issue in Google Cloud Function after following the steps described in the links attached above.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65220192/7334296), there's actually no need to package nltk as a local dependency—you could just include the data files with your code, and then append `nltk.data.path` with the `nltk_data` directory's path.