# Any way to import Python's nltk.download('punkt') into Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, nltk

Any way to import Python's nltk.download('punkt') into Google Cloud Functions? I've found that adding the statement manually into my code block in main.py significantly slows down my function processing, since punkt has to be downloaded every time it is run. Is there any method to eliminate this by calling punkt in some other way?

EDIT#1:- I edited my code and program structure to match what Barak suggested, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:

**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  [0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load [93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle[0m

  Searched in:
    - '/tmp/nltk_data'
    - '/env/nltk_data'
    - '/env/share/nltk_data'
    - '/env/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the instructions for [uploading files with your Cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system). Specifically since you can upload files, you can then modify nltk to just use these files:

Following the [official NLTK documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html), you can "Set your NLTK_DATA environment variable to point to your top level nltk_data folder."

Combining these together, you'd get:

1. Download the data (on your computer) with `python -m nltk.downloader punkt`
2. Upload the NLTK directory (find it's path on your computer in the above documentation) as an `nltk_data` directory, created at the root of your function environment
3. Configure the code to find that folder:

   ```
   import os
   root = os.path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
   nltk_dir = os.path.join(root, 'nltk_data')  # Your folder name here
   os.environ['NLTK_DATA'] = nltk_dir
   ```

EDIT: Seems as if path export with the environment variable doesn't achieve the desired effect, so let's have the path explicit in the code

1. On your computer download the data

   ```
   import os
   download_dir = os.path.abspath('my_nltk_dir')
   os.makedirs(download_dir)
   import nltk
   nltk.download('punkt', download_dir=download_dir)
   ```
2. Add the directory `my_nltk_dir` to be in the same folder of your python script. This would be

   ```
   PROJECT_ROOT/
   |-- my_code.py
   |-- my_nltk_dir/
       |-- ...
   ```
3. In your code refer to the data using

   ```
   import ntlk.data
   root = os.path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
   download_dir = os.path.join(root, 'my_nltk_dir')
   nltk.data.load(
       os.path.join(download_dir, 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
   )
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions. Firstly, should I provide a path anywhere in the above code to directly reach the required file? I've seen codes that add paths in place of 'nltk_data' but that didn't work for me. Second, is this code dependent on the device that I have hosted nltk on? Or can I just deploy the function then forget about my device altogether? Thanks once again.

Comment: @LuckyStrike - I added some more details since indeed there seems to be an issue with using the environment variable - I've detailed how to figure out the path of the nltk data specifically relative to your code, and you can just package it inside the zip containing your code - it should be able to run everywhere your function runs.

Comment: I've edited my question to match the current issue I'm facing, after reediting my code as per your suggestion. I've also added the same line as the last nltk.data.load function, but along with 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle', I added another load command for 'tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle' too.

Comment: @LuckyStrike - from the error it seems it's not really trying to combine the ntlk folder (it's trying to load `tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle`). Try fixing the code that does that, or alternatively try `os.chdir(download_dir)` before that code so when it tries loading from the current dir, that will also work. Without the code itself, that's the best guess I can provide.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as correct since the code is relatively faster (but not fast enough). Os.chdir did the trick. It seems there are inherent latency issues with using Google Cloud Functions since 2 years, making it much slower than Azure functions or AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 5):

Add nltk to your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs);

Install nltk on your local machine, if you haven't already:

```
pip install nltk
```

Then download the nltk_data files. In my case for tokenizers, I needed the [Punkt](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html) tokenizer module:

```
python -m nltk.downloader punkt
```

Copy them (they're inside Roaming/ for Windows) to your root folder (i.e. together with your functions):

```
cp -r C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\* YOUR\ROOT\FOLDER\nltk_data\
```

At the beginning of your main python function, or just before using nltk, add the following code--Basically, it grabs the [path where](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) nltk_data is, and tells [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) to look inside this folder:

```
  root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  download_dir = os.path.join(root, 'nltk_data')
  os.chdir(download_dir)
  nltk.data.path.append(download_dir)
```

Finally, after committing/pushing (if you're using Cloud Source Repos), (re)deploy your function!

Comment: I have up voted this answer because this worked for me. I had to remove the os.chdir part as that was causing an error. thank you for helping me out of this spot.

Comment: It works like a charm. As Farhan mentioned above you might only have to comment the "os.chdir(download_dir)" line (as i had to as well).